# pep8 and using a constructor as a validator

Tags: python, pep8

this is pretty trivial, but it's bugging me and I thought I'd throw it out there.

the python netaddr library is great.  I'm using it for a bunch of things, including IP address validation.  To do that, I use something like

```
try: 
    ddd = IPRange(split[0], split[1])
except:
    return False
```

And that works great but PEP8 hates that I'm creating 'ddd' but never using it. Is there another, better, cleaner way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: Don't bind `IPRange(split[0], split[1])` to a variable?

Comment: I would additionally put a comment above the `try:` line indicating that you want to check the validity of an IP-address. That should be clear enough!

Comment: Do you use `ddd` after try/except block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the "ddd" variable, then don't declare/assign it. If it's a module variable that could be used from another modules, you can not really avoid it. I would advise you to add a comment to explain why this variable is alone in the module.

Moreover it's considered bad practice to have a bare `except:`, you should use at least `except Exception:`

It's in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) too:

> When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare except: clause.

Comment: Where `Exception` can also be one of http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/api.html#custom-exceptions